# Tkinter: How to get the text of a frame for Radio Buttons made inside a loop of unknown iterations? (new to Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling with an example, my loop go through a list of an unknown length, and makes for each iteration 9 buttons and 1 frame for this buttons.

I have a problem, I can't fin a way to GET the value of a frame uppon pressing a button, here is the example:

```
UI_List_Frames=[]
RadioButtons_List=[]
def retrieve1():
    print(UI_List[0].get())
    print(UI_List_Frames[0]['text'])
    print('RRR')
def retrieve2():
    print(UI_List[1].get())
    print('SSS')

def retrieve6():
    print(UI_List[5].get())
    print('HHH')

def gettext(a):
    print('YY')
    print(a)
    print(UI_List_Frames[a]['text'])
    print(UI_List[5].get())
def gettext2(a):
    print('YY')
    #print(UI_List[a]['text']) #TypeError: 'IntVar' object is not subscriptable
ws2 = Tk()
ws2.title("Emplacement of your elements")
ws2.geometry('500x500')
Row_Now=0

ListExample=['EX1','EX2','EX3','EX4','EX5',]

UI_List=[]
for j in range(9):
    Variables_Per=IntVar()
    UI_List.append(Variables_Per)
    print('AAA3')
for i in range(len(ListExample)):
    print("iterationB: "+str(i))
    Its_name=ListExample[i]
    print(Its_name)
    SAVE0=i


    print("AAA0-")
    frame = LabelFrame(ws2, text=Its_name)
    print("AAA0")
    UI_List_Frames.append(frame)

    print('AAA1')
    print(str(i+1))
    print((str((i+1)%3)))
    if (i+1)%3==0: #Either 0 or 3 or 6 etc (i=5 means 6)
        Row_Now=Row_Now+1
    print('AAA1B')
    print(Row_Now)
    print(i-3*Row_Now)
    frame.grid(row=Row_Now, column=i-2*Row_Now, padx=10)
    print('AAA2')
    print('AAA4')   

    #Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='NW', variable=UI_List[i], value=1, command = retrieve()).grid(row=0, column=1)
    rb1=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='NW', variable=UI_List[i], value=1, command = retrieve1).grid(row=0, column=1)
    print('AAA5')
    rb2=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='N', variable=UI_List[i], value=2, command = retrieve2).grid(row=0, column=2)
    rb3=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='NE', variable=UI_List[i], value=3).grid(row=0, column=3)
    #rb3.pack()
    #rb3.bind('i', lambda event: self.show_rn("UU"))
    rb4=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='W', variable=UI_List[i], value=4, command=lambda i=i:gettext2(i)).grid(row=1, column=1)
    rb5=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='Center', variable=UI_List[i], value=5, command=lambda a=i:gettext(value)).grid(row=1, column=2)
    rb6=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='E', variable=UI_List[i], value=6, command = retrieve6).grid(row=1, column=3)
    print('AAA6')
    rb7=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='SW', variable=UI_List[i], value=7).grid(row=2, column=1)
    rb8=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='S', variable=UI_List[i], value=8).grid(row=2, column=2)
    rb9=Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i], text='SE', variable=UI_List[i], value=9, command=lambda a=b:gettext(2)).grid(row=2, column=3)
    print('AAA7')
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb1)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb2)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb3)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb4)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb5)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb6)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb7)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb8)
    RadioButtons_List.append(rb9)


ws2.mainloop()
```

I provided a ListExample, but in reality the list I want to use is of unknown length.

I am a new user of Tkinter, so I was experimenting several methods, you can see the commands associated to each radiobuttons.

My main focus is the function (gettext()) associated to the button (rb5), i want to find a way to give it a parameter that could inform us which frame it is (we have 5 frames here, one for EX1, then one for EX2, .. etc) But I can't find a way to do it.

After that I would simply be able to use this:

print(UI_List_Frames[a]['text'])

But my (a) variable does not follow the right frame. It does know which number it should be (0 for EX1, 1 for EX2.. etc)

I was able to get the value of the button by getting the right intvar (if its the first rb (rb1) then its the first value (1) and so on)

I can find a similar way to find the name of the frame, because this one changes every 9 iterations..

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHAFc.png

Comment: Look at the image, the code has been approved and an UI has been made, , the IntVar() variable has been made withing a différent loop (j loop), check it again. That is not the problem, my problem is : How to GET the right frame name?

Comment: So nobody knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to find a way to give it a parameter that could inform us
> which frame it is (we have 5 frames here, one for EX1, then one for
> EX2, .. etc) But I can't find a way to do it.

> But my (a) variable does not follow the right frame. It does know
> which number it should be (0 for EX1, 1 for EX2.. etc)

See line 11 in my script.

Note: You should not separate all defined functions for each `Radiobutton`. You should manipulate one function.

You should manipulate all `print()` functions into one defined function.

The Radiobutton widgets keyword `command` doesn't work for all `Radiobutton` widgets.

You should replace all `Radiobutton` widgets with keywors `command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)`

You don't need to do with `append`.

The UI_List[5].get() doesn't work. So set index to 4, meaning it is  in Ex4 index `NW`=1, `N`=2 and `NE`=3  and so on.

The correct way to get each `LabelFrame` and `Radiobutton` widgets by using this `UI_List[a].get()`. So you can get value for each `Radiobutton` within `LabelFrame`.

In `gettext` function, you can see all three(3) `print` functions. So you can see LabelFrame, postional, and index for each `Radiobutton`.

Avoid using wildcard such as `from tkinter import *`

Snippet modified:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

UI_List_Frames=[]
RadioButtons_List=[]
 

def gettext(a):
    print(UI_List_Frames[a]['text'])
    print(f'A {a}')
    print(UI_List[a].get())
    
    
 
ws2 = tk.Tk()
ws2.title("Emplacement of your elements")
ws2.geometry('500x500')
Row_Now = 0

ListExample = ['EX1','EX2','EX3','EX4','EX5',]

UI_List=[]

for j in range(9):
    Variables_Per = tk.IntVar()
    UI_List.append(Variables_Per)
      
for i in range(len(ListExample)):
    print(f"iterationB: {str(i)}")
    Its_name = ListExample[i]
    print(f'fName {Its_name}')
    
    frame = tk.LabelFrame(ws2, text=Its_name)
    UI_List_Frames.append(frame)
    print(f'Number {str(i+1)}')
    
    if not (i+1)%3: #Either 0 or 3 or 6 etc (i=5 means 6)
        Row_Now += 1
        
    frame.grid(row=Row_Now, column=i-2*Row_Now, padx=10)
  
    rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='NW',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=1,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='N',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=2,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=0, column=2)
    
    rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='NE',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=3,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=0, column=3)
    
    rb4 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='W',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=4,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    rb5 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='Center',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=5,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    rb6 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='E',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=6,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=1, column=3)
    
    rb7 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='SW',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=7,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=2, column=1)
    
    rb8 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='S',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=8,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=2, column=2)
    
    rb9 = tk.Radiobutton(UI_List_Frames[i],
                         text='SE',
                         variable=UI_List[i],
                         value=9,
                         command=lambda i=i:gettext(i)).grid(row=2, column=3)
     
ws2.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]